# Didn't get the new token google authorization

Tags: android, google-oauth

Whenever I try to obtain a new access_token for accessing user emails using refresh_token I get the error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
}
```

I tried hitting the [URL](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token) using postman with

```
 code:1/XXXXXXXX 
 client_id:XXXXXXXXX
 client_secret:XXXXXXXXXX
 grant_type:authorization_code
 redirect_uri:http://localhost
 access_type:offline
```

and instead of getting the new access_token and refresh_token every time I get the malformed auth code

Answer (score 2):

Here is my case:

The authorization code in the url hash fragment is `encodeURIComponent`, so if you pass this code to request access token. It will throw an error:

`{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Malformed auth code." }`

So I use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the authorization code.

```
decodeURIComponent('4%2F_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY')
```

After decode, the authorization code is:

```
"4/_QCXwy-PG5Ub_JTiL7ULaCVb6K-Jsv45c7TPqPsG2-sCPYMTseEtqHWcU_ynqWQJB3Vuw5Ad1etoWqNPBaGvGHY"
```